# Including Youtube-dl in FFMPEG not working in Bash (OSX)

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I am trying to download 5 second samples for a list of youtube video. The traditional approach is to download the entire file with "youtube-dl" and then use "ffmpeg" to split it however you want it.

I am trying to use the following method: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/622#issuecomment-162337869

It does work when I include the variables in the command, for example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i $(youtube-dl -f best --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySVi-0RS5vI&t=5s) -t 10 -c:v copy -c:a copy title2.mp4
```

However, I am having issues trying to automate the system. Specifically, I would like ffmpeg and youtube-dl to read a file and use the values. I created the file "youtube.txt" which includes the following codes:

```
440.8,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-4wOE_DNeA,661.2,881.6,0-4wOE_DNeA
330,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-AMWW6tHzw,495,660,0-AMWW6tHzw
509.2,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-Rmto2rgMw,763.8,1018.4,0-Rmto2rgMw
427.6,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-U53qm45cA,641.4,855.2,0-U53qm45cA
320.4,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-dja9Ys4Sg,480.6,640.8,0-dja9Ys4Sg
343.6,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-g_PulsqtM,515.4,687.2,0-g_PulsqtM
415.6,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-nniRyn7dU,623.4,831.2,0-nniRyn7dU
431.2,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=006BQU3BFxw,646.8,862.4,006BQU3BFxw
```

I am using the following command:

```
parallel -j 6 --colsep ',' ffmpeg -ss {1} -i $(youtube-dl -f best --get-url {2}) --t 5 -c:v copy -c:a copy {5} :::: youtube.txt
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: '{2}' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:{2}" ) to search YouTube
--t: No such file or directory
```

Would you mind helping me?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on a bash script for you if that works.  What are the 3rd and 4th arguments in your csv file?

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot! I'm actually trying to extract 5s of video at three points in time: at #1, #2 and #4. #5 is for the file name.

Comment: I assume you mean #1, 3, 4?

Comment: I've got it written, if no one else gets to it before I post... But just hopped on a flight out of LAX. Ill get it to you tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ok thanks, please let me know.

Comment: submitted a solution in python, which natively handles csv files

Comment: Let me know if the python script works for ya

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using python2, so this should work on the python version shipped with MacOS. My original bash script was choking on the csv line reading for some reason. Add this script to `getvids.py` in the same directory as your `youtube.txt`, then run `chmod +x getvids.py` and when you're ready to turn it loose `./getvids.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv, os

with open('youtube.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
            starttimes = [row[0], row[2], row[3]]
            yturl = os.popen('youtube-dl -f best --get-url '+row[1]).read().strip()
            for thistime in starttimes:
                    print(row[1] + ' @time='+thistime)
                    os.system('ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -ss '
                        +thistime+' -i "'+yturl+'" -t 5 -c copy '+row[4]+'['+thistime+'s].mp4')
```